# Is There a "Pig Painting" Timeline?

Tags: united-states, police, freedom-of-speech, house-of-representatives

On May 6<sup>th</sup> 2016, [Representative Lacy Clay congratulated David Pulphus on his painting "Untitled #1"](https://lacyclay.house.gov/media-center/press-releases/clay-salutes-2016-congressional-art-competition-winners) and at some point the painting made it to Washington where Representative Clay hung it in the Cannon Tunnel on Capitol Hill.

I'm not certain when that happened. The first press I saw on it was Dec 29<sup>th</sup>: http://ijr.com/2016/12/766256-painting-of-cops-as-pigs-hung-proudly-in-u-s-capitol/ The painting was given the colloquial name of the "Pig Painting" and news about it quickly went sparked national controversy.

[Fox reports](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2017/01/17/capitol-hill-pig-painting-permanently-removed-after-uproar.html) that "Untitled #1" has now been taken down permanently. Citing Representative Duncan Hunter's removal of the picture on Jan 6<sup>th</sup> and then say that Representative Clay rehung "Untitled #1" and:

> From there, the painting became a political football – with other Republicans stepping forward to remove the painting, only for Clay’s office to put it back up again

I was hoping someone could give me an actual timeline of when all the hangings and unhangings happened. Was this only unhung twice by other Representatives? Fox's statement could be interpreted either way.

Answer (score 1):

*Q: Is There a "Pig Painting" Timeline?*

As noted, the painting was selected on May 6, 2016.

According to *[Newsmax](https://www.newsmax.com/politics/duncan-hunter-painting-policemen-pigs/2017/01/10/id/767813/)* the "artwork, which depicts a police officer as a pig in uniform aiming a gun at black protesters, has been on display in the hallway between the Capitol and adjacent House office buildings since June [2016] ..."

[As of January 5, 2017](https://www.kqed.org/arts/12584610/bay-area-police-call-for-pig-headed-cop-paintings-removal-from-u-s-capitol), "law enforcement groups around the country Thursday call[ed] on House Speaker Paul Ryan to remove a painting from the U.S. Capitol complex."

[Rep. Duncan Hunter](https://www.newsmax.com/politics/duncan-hunter-painting-policemen-pigs/2017/01/10/id/767813/) "took down the painting Friday [January 6, 2017] after law enforcement officers protested the display ..."

The *[Washington Times](https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2017/jan/11/doug-lamborn-cops-pigs-painting-hateful-and-divisi/)* reports that "On Tuesday [January 10, 2017], Mr. Clay rehung it, and Mr. Lamborn was among several Republican congressmen who took it down again."

The *[Washington Examiner](https://www.washingtonexaminer.com/cops-as-pigs-painting-permanently-removed-from-capitol)* reports that "Four different Republican congressman took it down three times last week, and Clay hung it back on the wall each time.

As noted, the painting was [permanently removed](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/capitol-hill-pig-painting-permanently-removed-after-uproar) from the Cannon tunnel on Capitol Hill January 17, 2017. Further, Clay "now has the painting on display in his Capitol Hill office"; but "vowed to have [the] decision reversed."

*[U.S.News](https://www.usnews.com/news/national-news/articles/2017-04-18/painting-of-cops-as-pigs-cant-be-rehung-in-capitol)*, on April 18, 2017, reported that a federal judge "rejected a request to rehang [the] painting".